# How to use Charles to observe network mobile traffic over 3G/4G

Tags: charles-proxy

I need to observe network traffic when mobile is connected over 3G/4G. I could do it when mobile is connected over wi-fi

I tried enabling mobile hotspot and connecting laptop to it. But this didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vikram

Comment: Find one article. Wish it helps: https://www.adopsinsider.com/ad-ops-tools/charles-proxy-mobile-cellular/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is possible with a proxy trick, for example using [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/):

1. Get and install a proxy tool (like Charles) on your PC(or mac).
2. Set a proxy on a specific PORT (like 6995).
3. Know your PC(or mac) local IP address.
4. Set the new proxy (*Your_PC_IP:PORT*) on your device(iPhone or Android, no different)
5. Then in your proxy tool you can lick all of the networks traffics

Answer (score -2):

Which device you are using to make Mobile Hotspot iOS or Android.
We need to configure that device also with Charles.
**Few points**
1-In Charles, go to Proxy>>Proxy Settings and select the SSL tab. Add your host to the list of Locations

Refer this: https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/

Once configured correctly We can see network traffics and the throttle the network.